# How to Show image in AspxImage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to show image by selecting it from Documents folder in my PC in desktop.

I am writing:

```
 ASPxImage1.ImageUrl = "C:\\Documents\\Pictures\\AspxImage.png";
```

But this is not showing anything. How to show this image?

Comment: aspx code is translated into html and jabvascript which runs in a browser. That URL has to be relative to a server root ...

Comment: So i must have to save image on server? @EmmanuelN

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** Web Applications does not have the permissions to `access` the `Local Drives` of the `client machines` due to security concerns.

**Solution** : you need to create a folder called `Images` in your `project` folder and access it using `relative path`.

Try This:

```
ASPxImage1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Images/AspxImage.png");
```

Comment: Server.MapPath takes a relative url and returns the local path. you are trying to do the opposite.